# UiWebView Obj-C how to cleanup a Javascript app with leaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiwebview

My iPad app has a webview that contains an app written in jQuery. It is pretty heavy in that it loads Base64 strings from SQLite.

In the Intstruments Allocations profiler the memory allocations keep increasing and only ever decreasing by miniscule amounts.

I am using the FMDB wrapper for SQLite and have written my own functions that init string so I can release them directly after sending to the UIWebView. It hasn't helped the allocations count, so my next port of call is the WebView jQuery app.

Since I haven't written the jQuery I don't know where to look.

Is there a way that I can remove/release/flush the UIWebView and then re-create it and reload my web app?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you find an answer?

Comment: No not, yet still working on it. I will update here if I get an answer.

My current thoughts are that the UIWebView itself is caching data and it's not necessarily a Javascript/jQuery issue.

I need to figure out how to tell the UIWebView not to cache stuff.

Comment: I have also figured it out from testing. It keeps on adding memory over time. Seems these are not cleared properly by the UIWebView itself. Hence any alternative we can use for displaying web content?

Comment: Nope, not at all, unfortunately. I tried many, many techniques and there was still a leak somewhere. I am 99% sure the problem was with iOS and not my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of theorising about what might be wrong, you can take the jQuery app out and use it in browser. Use Chrome dev tools to check what the memory usages are and you can pinpoint leaks to pages more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Also I think its interesting to look at the google search API app in app store. They are kind of using a web view but it works perfectly. Any ideas about that?